# Loop through user input with getchar

Tags: c, user-interface, loops, getchar

I have written a small script to detect the full value from the user input with the `getchar()` function in C. As `getchar()` only returns the first character i tried to loop through it... The code I have tried myself is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a = getchar();
    int b = strlen(a);

    for(i=0; i<b; i++) {
        printf("%c", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this code does not give me the full value of the user input.

Comment: Read about `strlen()` first... It accepts `char[]` type of input not `char`.

Comment: You're doing `strlen()` on a `char`. This leads to undefined behavior and you can get anything as return value... You should change your loop logic!

Answer (score 5):

You can do looping part this way

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

Comment: An old-shool approach: `while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n') putchar(c);`. By the way you probably meant `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: this code didnt works for me ..can you please give me a working demo

Comment: @mysqllover please give a link with your full code in it

Answer (score 3):

`getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`. And it only returns one char per iteration. It returns, however `EOF` once input terminates.

You do not check for EOF (you actually cannot detect that instantly when `getchar()` to `char`).

a is a `char`, not an array, neither a string, you cannot apply `strlen()` to it.

`strlen()` returns `size_t`, which is unsigned.

Enable most warnings, your compiler wants to help you.

Sidenote: `char` can be signed or unsigned.

Read a C book! Your code is soo broken and you confused multiple basic concepts. - no offense!

For a starter, try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;

    while ( 1 ) {

        ch = getchar();
    x:  if ( ch == EOF )     // done if input terminated
            break;

        printf("%c", ch);    // %c takes an int-argument!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to terminate on other strings, too, `#include <string.h>` and replace line `x:` by:

```
if ( ch == EOF || strchr("\n\r\33", ch) )
```

That will terminate if `ch` is one of the chars listed in the string literal (here: newline, return, ESCape). However, it will also match ther terminating `'\0'` (not sure if you can enter that anyway).

Storing that into an array is shown in good C books (at least you will learn how to do it yourself).

Answer (score 2):

- **Point 1:** In your code, `a` is not of array type. you cannot use array subscript operator on that.
- **Point 2:** In your code, `strlen(a);` is wrong. `strlen()` calculates the length of a *string*, i.e, a null terminated `char` array. You need to pass a pointer to a string to [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen).
- **Point 3:** `getchar()` does not loop for itself. You need to put `getchar()` inside a loop to keep on reading the input.
- **Point 4:** `getchar()` retruns an `int`. You should change the variable type accordingly.
- **Point 5:** The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Keeping the above points in mind,we can write a pesudo-code, which will look something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int main(void)                        // nice signature. :-)
{
    char arr[MAX]  = {0};            //to store the input
    int ret = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)      //don't want to overrrun array
    {
      if ( (ret = getchar())!= EOF)  //yes, getchar() returns int
      {
            arr[i] = ret;
            printf("%c", arr[i]);
      }
      else
           ;//error handling
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See here <kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://rextester.com/BDOM44440)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` : get a char (one character) not a string like you want

use `fgets()` : get a string or  `gets()`(Not recommended) or `scanf()` (Not recommended)

but first you need to allocate the size of the string : `char S[50]`
or use a `malloc` ( `#include<stdlib.h>` ) :

```
char *S;
S=(char*)malloc(50);
```

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast `void *` to pointers! Using a magic number is plain wrong.

Comment: Never speak of `gets`; it is dangerous and deprecated. Always recommend at least `fgets`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to read a line (your question mentions a "full value" but you don't explain what that means).

You might simply use [fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) for that purpose, with the limitation that you have to provide a fixed size line buffer (and handle - or ignore - the case when a line is larger than the buffer). So you would code

```
char linebuf[80];
memset (linebuf, 0, sizeof(linbuf)); // clear the buffer
char* lp = fgets(linebuf, sizeof(linebuf), stdin);
if (!lp) { 
  // handle end-of-file or error
}
else if (!strchr(lp, '\n')) {
  /// too short linebuf
}
```

If you are on a POSIX system (e.g. Linux or MacOSX), you could use [getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) (which dynamically allocates a buffer). If you want some line edition facility on Linux, consider also [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)

<sup>Avoid as a plague the obsolete `gets`</sup>

Once you have read a line into some buffer, you can parse it (e.g. using manual parsing, or [sscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sscanf.html) -notice the useful `%n` conversion specification, and test the result count of `sscanf`-, or [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) -notice that it can give you the ending pointer- etc...).